# Unexpected behaviour of FOR loop in Angular app

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is most probably a silly mistake but I can't see the issue. I'm trying to create an array of objects for an image gallery in my Angularjs app. Each photo object has a `thumb` and `img` attribute. The `for` loop is creating the objects fine and I'm logging each to the console to check them:

```
{thumb: "/10000/0_t.jpg", img: "/10000/0_l.jpg"}
{thumb: "/10000/1_t.jpg", img: "/10000/1_l.jpg"}
{thumb: "/10000/2_t.jpg", img: "/10000/2_l.jpg"}
...
```

However, after running this code:

```
var images = [];
var image = {};
for (var i = 0; i < property.images.length; i++) {
    image.thumb = "/" + property.id + "/" + i + "_t.jpg";
    image.img = "/" + property.id + "/" + i + "_l.jpg";
    console.log(image); //this gives expected output
    images.push(image);
};
console.log(images); //this gives all entries as the same
```

the final `console.log` gives me:

```
{thumb: "/10000/27_t.jpg", img: "/10000/27_l.jpg"} //X28
```

for each image. The 27 comes from the fact that there are 28 images but I can't understand why they all have the same paths?

Comment: Closure, look it up...

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl I'm not sure it has anything to do with closures...

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl, even a closure would reference the same object in each iteration; what you're thinking of is a completely different problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to make a new object on each iteration:

```
var image;
for (var i = 0; i < property.images.length; i++) {
    image = {};
    image.thumb = "/" + property.id + "/" + i + "_t.jpg";
    image.img = "/" + property.id + "/" + i + "_l.jpg";
    console.log(image); //this gives expected output
    images.push(image);
};
```

If you don't, then each iteration will re-use that same original object. Passing an object to `.push()` does not make a copy.

Comment: you beat me by a seconds :D

Comment: About to accept your answer - could you just explain why the `console.log` inside the loop shows the "expected" output?

Comment: @tommyd456 Your code was successfully *updating* the object, but since there was only one object involved you were just seeing those successive updates. When the contents of `image` were updated, it would appear to change everywhere it was referenced, which would include all of the earlier array entries.

Comment: @tommyd456 if you had had a `console.log(images)` *inside* the loop, it might have been more apparent.

Comment: @tommyd456 no your `console.log(images);` (in the code you posted at least) is **after** the end of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

how about this:

```
var path = "/" + property.id + "/";
var images = property.images.map((img,i)=>{
    return {
        thumb: path + i + "_t.jpg",
        img: path + i + "_l.jpg"
    }
});
console.log(images);
```

Answer (score 0):

Works just fine for me. Please, *limit your scope* as much as possible in JavaScript.

Refer to chapter 16 *[Introducing a New Scope via an IIFE](http://speakingjs.com/es5/ch16.html#iife)* in the book; *Speaking JavaScript*.

***Note:*** An IIFE is an "immediately invoked function expression."

```js
var property = {
  id : 10000,
  images: [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 3 }]
};

var images = [];

for (var i = 0; i < property.images.length; i++) {
  (function(){
    var image = {}; // This should be inside the loop.
                    // This way the scope does not leak.
    image.thumb = "/" + property.id + "/" + i + "_t.jpg";
    image.img = "/" + property.id + "/" + i + "_l.jpg";
    
    images.push(image);
  }());
};

document.body.innerHTML = '<pre>' + JSON.stringify(images, null, 4) + '</pre>';
```

Comment: JavaScript ES5 doesn't have block-scope, the last value of `image` remains after the for loop in this example. In JavaScript ES6, you can use `let` instant of `var`. (`let` has block-scope). In ES5, you can either delete `image` after the for loop or use an anonymous function to create a closure scope. But in order to keep it simple, I would just wrap the whole code into a function.

Comment: There's really no need for an additional layer of scope here; the problem is simpler than that.